# Azure DevOps Server: Set Rule on Inherited Process - Cannot set more than one rule using 'User Groups' to restrict state transitions

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

Dears,

I'm trying to set rules on my inherited 'Process' to restrict state transition based on the 'User Group' using more than one rule. but system displays error message at the same, the I can set any number of rule using the same conditions on trail Web version of 'Azure Devops' is working fine.

Could anyone please support on the below issue.

In my organization, we are using the on-premise Azure DevOps Server.

version no:
Dev18.M170.7

In Azure DevOps server, For example,

I have created a copy of the existing 'Agile' process.

Updated the 'Bug' workflow by adding new states.

Added user groups called - Dev, QA, BA etc.. And added members to the group.

Adding custom rules to restrict bug state flow based on user group.

Setting Rules as below:

Rule Name: Dev

Condition:
Current user is not member of Group - DEV (group name)

Action:
Restrict state transition to 'Testing'.

Rule Name: QA

1. Condition:
   Current user is not member of Group - QA (group name)

Action:
Restrict state transition to 'Closed'.

I am getting the below error message, as soon as I am trying to save the second rule:

VS1640113: It is not allowed to have multiple rules with the same action type using the same conditions. The rules ['Dev', 'QA'] have the action type 'ProhibitedValues' using the same conditions. Change the conditions of the rule to fix this error.

Note:
But, at the same time I am able to successfully set similar conditions on rules (more than one) in free trail version of DevOps 'https://dev.azure.com/'.

Please update me, if anyone has any workaround/clarification for the same.

[Attached image of the error message][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGohV.png

Comment: Hi @Vasanthkumar, Is the explanations in my answer helpful to you? If you have any questions about this, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, new features or new versions of features are first deployed to the cloud Azure DevOps (**Azure DevOps Services**), then gradually deployed to on-premise Azure DevOps (**Azure DevOps Server**).

Sometimes, on **Azure DevOps Services**, between two organizations that are in different regions, even have the different features or different versions of features.

It is reasonable that there will be delays in the deployment of new features between different regions and between cloud and on-premise.

Please wait few of days, then try again to see if the problem is fixed.